# How to show $\beta$ is associated to $\alpha_B$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

https://www.zhihu.com/question/264128942?from=profile_question_card

$f:X\to Y,\textrm{ where }$$X=\operatorname{Spec}B,Y=\operatorname{Spec}A.$
$f^{\sharp}(Y):A\to B.$

Let $K=A^{(I)},L=A^{(J)}$.

$\alpha:A^{(I)}\to A^{(J)}$

$\alpha_B:A^{(I)}\otimes_AB\to A^{(J)}\otimes_AB$
\begin{array}[c]{ccc}
\widetilde{A^{(I)}\otimes_AB}&\stackrel{\textrm{associated to $\alpha_B$}}\rightarrow&\widetilde{A^{(J)}\otimes_AB}\\
\downarrow\scriptstyle{\varphi}&&{\downarrow}\scriptstyle{\psi}\\
f^{-1}\widetilde{A^{(I)}}\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y}\mathcal O_X &\stackrel{\beta}{\rightarrow}&f^{-1}\widetilde{A^{(J)}}\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y}\mathcal O_X
\end{array}
$\forall \mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}B, \mathfrak q=(f^{\sharp}(Y))^{-1}(\mathfrak p).$
$\textrm{According to Lemma 1.2.10 and Corollary 1.1.11 in Liu Qing,}$
$(A^{(I)}\otimes_AB)_{\mathfrak p}\simeq
(A^{(I)}\otimes_AB)\otimes_BB_{\mathfrak p}\simeq A^{(I)}\otimes_AB_{\mathfrak p}\simeq (A^{(I)}\otimes_AA_{\mathfrak q})\otimes_{A_{\mathfrak q}}B_{\mathfrak p}\simeq (A^{(I)})_{\mathfrak q}\otimes_{A_{\mathfrak q}}B_{\mathfrak p}$
$\forall g\in B, \textrm{we have}$
$(A^{(I)}\otimes_AB)_g\simeq (A^{(I)}\otimes_AB)\otimes_BB_g\simeq A^{(I)}\otimes_AB_g $

$\varphi(D(g))\textrm{ is defined by}$
 $(A^{(I)}\otimes_AB)_g\simeq A^{(I)}\otimes_AB_g\to (f^{-1}\widetilde{A^{(I)}})(D(g))\otimes_{(f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y)(D(g))}B_g\to (f^{-1}\widetilde{A^{(I)}}\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y}\mathcal O_X)(D(g))$
$\psi(D(g))\textrm{ is defined the same as above.}$

It is easy to verify $\varphi,\psi$ are respectively isomorphic and the above diagram is commutative.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: If $K,L$ are any $A$-modules, the above conclusion is always established as true, isn't it?